# Azure: get current balance of single resource through REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-billing-api

I am looking to get the real-time current amount spent by a given resource (not the whole subscription or a resource group) during the current period on MS Azure through Azure's REST API (e.g.: We have spent X$ so far this month on this resource).  I have dug around the Billing API and general REST API documentation (and also their node.js SDK), but I can't find anything that seems to do that.

Has anyone ever done something similar?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron you're right, I forgot, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note to this doc: [Azure consumption API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-consumption-api-overview) , here shows that you can use **Usage Details API** with filter to get what you want:

> - **Filtering** - Trim your API result set down to a smaller set of usage    detail records using the following filters:
>
>   - Usage end / usage start
>   - Resource Group
>   - Resource Name

Here is the format of this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$expand={$expand}&$filter={$filter}&$skiptoken={$skiptoken}&$top={$top}&$apply={$apply}&api-version=2019-01-01
```

For `{scope}`, except can use '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/' for subscription scope,  it can also use '/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{billingAccountId}' for Billing Account scope and etc. For more details, reference this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list).

Use `$filter={$filter}` can achieve what you want(access specific resource), here provided my API can for your reference:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$expand=meterDetails,additionalProperties&$filter=properties/usageEnd ge '2019-01-1' AND properties/usageEnd le '2019-05-22' AND properties/instanceName eq '{instanceName}'&$top=30&api-version=2019-01-01
```

> `eq` means equals,  `ge` means greater or equal, `le` means less or
>   equal, and the instanceNmae means your specific resource name that the usage is about.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the 'properties/' thing, I was missing that and now my query runs.

Answer (score 2):

Azure [Billing APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list) can be used to pull usage and resource data into your preferred data analysis tools.

The `Azure Resource Usage API` and `Azure Resource RateCard API` can help accurately predict and manage costs. The APIs are implemented as a Resource Provider and part of the family of APIs exposed by the Azure Resource Manager.

**Recommended Steps**

1. Use the [Azure Resource Usage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview#azure-resource-usage-api-preview) to get the list of available
   Azure resources and estimated pricing information for each.
2. Use [Azure Resource RateCard API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview#azure-resource-ratecard-api-preview) to get your estimated Azure
   consumption data.

> **Note:** Support for Pay-as-you-go, MSDN, Monetary commitment, and Monetary credit offers (EA and [CSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/billing/azure-csp-pricelist#get-prices-by-using-the-azure-rate-card) not supported)

3. Azure [Invoice Download API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview#azure-invoice-download-api-preview) allows you to Access your Azure
   invoice in PDF Format once the [opt-in has been complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-manage-access#opt-in). It can
   be used to pull usage and resource data into preferred data analysis
   tools.

> **Note:** This feature is in first version of preview and may be subject to backward-incompatible changes. Currently, it's not
>   available for certain subscription offers (EA, CSP, AIO not supported)
>   and Azure Germany.

4. [Reporting APIs for EA customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-usage-detail) - Usage Details offers a daily
   breakdown of consumed quantities and estimated charges by an
   Enrollment. The result also includes information on instances,
   meters, and departments. The API can be queried by Billing period or
   by a specified start and end date

**Recommended Documents**

1. [Azure Billing REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/)
2. [Azure Billing API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview)
3. [Azure Resource Manager overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview)
4. [REST API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/?view=Azure)

If you still have any query feel free o share. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The API you would want to look at is [`Consumption API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/) and the operation you would want to use is [`Usage Details - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list).

Please note that:

- For `{scope}` parameter, please specify `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/`.
- To get consumption for a particular resource you will need to specify that resource's path in `$filter`.

For example, if you want the consumption for a particular storage account for say the month of April 2019, this is how your filter criteria looks like:

```
$filter=properties/instanceId eq '/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storage-account-name}' and properties/usageStart ge '2019-04-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' and properties/usageEnd lt '2019-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z'&$expand=meterDetails,additionalProperties
```